# Apache Server-Side Includes Refuse to Work (Tried everything in the docs but still no joy)

Tags: apache

Trying to get apache server-side includes to work.  Really simple - just want to include a footer on each page.

Apache 2.2:

```
# ./httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec  4 2011 18:24:53
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.7.2 rev9999
```

mod_include is compiled in:

```
# /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -l | grep mod_include
  mod_include.c
```

And it's in httpd.conf:

```
# grep shtml httpd.conf
AddType text/html .shtml
DirectoryIndex index.html.var index.htm index.html index.shtml index.xhtml index.wml index.perl index.pl index.plx index.ppl index.cgi index.jsp index.js index.jp index.php4 index.php3 index.php index.phtml default.htm default.html home.htm index.php5 Default.html Default.htm home.html
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
```

In the web directory I created a .htaccess with

```
Options +Includes
```

And then in the document, I have:

```
<h1>next should be the include</h1>
<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->
<h1>include done</h1>
```

And I see nothing in between those headers.  Tried file=, also with/without absolute path.

Is there something else I'm missing?

I see the same thing on another unrelated server (more or less stock CentOS 6), so I suspect the problem is between keyboard and chair...

Comment: If you have PHP available, you can rename the document from file.html to file.php and just add `<?php include('footer.html'); ?>` instead of `<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->`. Everything else would stay exactly the same.

Comment: Yep, know all about PHP :-)  Was trying to avoid using the overhead in this case by using apache's SSI since it's just static content.

Answer (score 1):

From my WampDeveloper (Wamp package) configuration:

```
<IfModule include_module>
<Directory "C:/WampDeveloper/Websites/*/webroot">
Options +Includes
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html .shtml
</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

You probably are missing the AddOutputFilter directive that assigns file extensions to be processed by the SSI filter or are using an incorrect AddHandler filter-name.